# How to add Nested presenter to slot, that will change browser url to presenter's name token when revealing?

Tags: gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform

How to add Nested presenter to slot, that will change browser url to presenter's name token when revealing?

I use GWT 2.7 and GWTP 1.5.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reverse your logic.

Set url in your browser and this would reveal your presenter.

Answer (score 0):

You use the [place manager](https://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/core/navigation/reveal-places.html)

From the link:

some sample code:

```
@Inject
CarsPresenter(
        EventBus eventBus,
        MyView view,
        MyProxy proxy,
        PlaceManager placeManager) {
    super(eventBus, view, proxy, ApplicationPresenter.SLOT_MAIN);

    this.placeManager = placeManager;
}

    public void displayCar(String model) {
    PlaceRequest placeRequest = new PlaceRequest.Builder()
            .nameToken(NameTokens.CARS)
            .with(ParameterTokens.MODEL, model)
            .build();

    placeManager.revealPlace(placeRequest);
}
```

This will cause the presenter identified by NameTokens.CAR to be revealed and the prepareFromRequest method called in that presenter...